# How to scroll images horizontally having two columns upper row contain even images and lower row contain odd images

Tags: react-native

**Hii I want  to scroll images horizontally having two columns upper row contain even images and lower row contain odd images, but i dont know how to do this**

**code to fetch api**

```
componentDidMount(){
return fetch('https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccLAsEcOSq?indent=1')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: responseJson.book_array,
    }, function(){
    });
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
  });}
```

**code for render**

```
render() {
if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
  return <ActivityIndicator color={'red'} />;
}
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContainerStyle={{height:300, flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
        {this.state.dataSource.map(item => this.renderItem(item))}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

}
}

**code for renderItem**

```
renderItem(item) {
return (
  <View style={{ margin: 5 }}>
    <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        marginBottom: 1,
      }}>

         <Image  style={{ width: 150,height: 150}}
                      source={{uri: item.image}}/>
    </View> 
    <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        marginBottom: 1,
      }}>
         <Image  style={{ width: 150,height: 150}}
                      source={{uri: item.image}}/>
    </View> 
  </View>
);
```

}

Comment: I tried your code in snack expo. it is working. can you elaborate more about what you exactly want? here is expo link: https://snack.expo.io/B1I_Cx8OE

Comment: hii Shashin , both columns are displaying same images and i need my scrollview to display only even images like(0,2,4,6) in upper row and similarly bottom row to display odd images which i fetch from api.